# Choose the correct answer between "shouldn't" and "mustn't"

Tags: word-choice

Here is the question:

> He ... want the job, or he would be here.
>
> a)doesn't have to
>
> b)mustn't
>
> c)shouldn't
>
> d)must

I'm in doubt between b and c. It seems both of them are correct. If we consider that sentence as an implication, maybe "mustn't" is the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word that fits is "**mustn't**".  It indicates that a logical deduction is being made:  If he wanted the job he would be here;  He isn't here; Therefore he does not want the job.

The word "mustn't" is not a stronger version of "shouldn't" in this case, because it *doesn't* indicate that the absentee is *forbidden* from wanting the job.  Rather, it is a stronger version of "probably doesn't", like "certainly doesn't".  It *must* be true that he does not want the job, because that follows logically from his actions.

This is the 4th definition of **must** here in [Merriam-Webester](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must):

> 4 : be logically inferred (see INFER sense 1) or supposed to, 
>   e.g., "it must be time"